# ZeroMQ cache on disk

Tags: zeromq

Does ZeroMQ support caching messages on disk out of the box?
I.e if server is offline (or even always before send) I want to store messages on disk.
If not, what pattern should I use for many clients that push data to server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not. It supports in-memory message buffers only; different sockets types have different buffers, some have send or receive buffers only (like PUB and SUB), some have both types of buffers (like ROUTER).

If you need to save messages to disk, you have to roll your own solution in ZeroMq, but you're better off using a standard JMS or MQ-based messaging product that supports persistent messaging; no reason to reinvent the wheel.